# How to get an nth item from a JSON object

Tags: java, android, json

I want to retrieve the first object from the json below:

```
"categories": {
        "Blues": {
          "ID": 5,
          "name": "Blues",
          "year": "1980"
        },
        "Reggae": {
          "ID": 62,
          "name": "Reggae",
          "year": "1992",
        }
      },
      ...

  }
```

Currently, i am parsing it like this:

```
   JSONObject catsObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("categories");
                  JSONArray names = catsObject.names();
                  JSONObject categObj = object.getJSONObject(names.get(0).toString());
                  String year = categObj.getString("year");
                  Log.d(TAG, "The year is " + year);
```

But Line `JSONObject categObj = object.getJSONObject(names.get(0).toString());` is returning this error

10-19 22:14:42.554 29056-29056/com.ozuf.musichistory W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for Blues

Comment: What is `object`? I think you want `JSONObject categObj = catsObject.getJSONObject(names.get(0).toString());` instead.

Comment: `object ` is not defined, thinking that's a mistake

Comment: @azurefrog thanks. That fixed it.